# Why this Quadtree Query often returns nothing?

Tags: java, search, processing, collision-detection, quadtree

*Any "W" refers to half-width and any "H" refers to half-height. Any "X" and "Y" refers to the center of a rectangle aligned with the co-ordinate axes.*

I am attempting to write some general purpose quadtree code for use in physics simulations and game design. At first it was returning ALL points in the contents of a quadtree that was completely enclosed by the search region. After adding a bunch of print() statements to illuminate the process I managed to solve that problem but now I have a new one I can't seem to figure out. For some reason when I query the quadtree for the "Placeables" within a rectangular region  I either get a totally correct result, but more often than not I get nothing returned at all. Placeables are defined as follows:

```
abstract class Placeable{ //things that can be stored in quadtree
  PVector pos;
  abstract void show();}
```

The important parts of the quadtree code:

```
class Quadtree{ //Data structure for storing objects in 2D
  Quadtree nw,ne,sw,se; //children
  Quadtree parent;
  ArrayList<Placeable> contents;//contents of THIS branch only, child object contents not included
  float x,y,w,h;//center point, half-width and half-height
  boolean divided;  //false if leaf node
  static final int capacity = 6; //controls maximum capacity all quadtree nodes for case-by-case tuning 
...

...
boolean intersects(float rX, float rY, float rW, float rH){//Do I intersect with the rectangle defined by rX,rY,rW,rH?
    return !(rX-rW >= x+w || rX+rW <= x-w 
          || rY-rH >= y+h || rY+rH <= y-h);}
      
  //return all Placeables inside a rectangular region
  ArrayList<Placeable> query(float X, float Y, float W, float H){
    return query(X,Y,W,H,new ArrayList<Placeable>());}
  ArrayList<Placeable> query(float X, float Y, float W, float H, ArrayList<Placeable> found){
    print("Querying:",contents.size(),"/",Integer.toString(capacity),"\t");
    
    if (!intersects(X,Y,W,H)){ //if no intersection, return arraylist unmodified
      print("Does Not Intersect\n");
      return found;
    } else {  //if intersection, check contents for Placeables within the region
      print("Does Intersect!\n");
      for (Placeable p : contents){
        if ( (p.pos.x <= X+W) && (p.pos.x >= X-W) //capitals refer to search region
          && (p.pos.y <= Y+H) && (p.pos.y >= Y-H) ){
          found.add(p);
          print("Found Point\t",p.pos.x,"\t",p.pos.y,"\n");}
      }
      if (divided){ //after checking own contents, recursively query children appending to same array
        print("Descending\n");
        print("NW ");
        nw.query(X,Y,W,H,found);
        print("NE ");
        ne.query(X,Y,W,H,found);
        print("SW ");
        sw.query(X,Y,W,H,found);
        print("SE ");
        se.query(X,Y,W,H,found);
        print("Raising\n");}
      return found;
    }
  }
.....
}
```

The following is an example of correct output in a 1024x768 window:

```
Querying: 6 / 6     Does Intersect!
Descending
NW Querying: 6 / 6  Does Not Intersect
NE Querying: 6 / 6  Does Intersect!
Descending
NW Querying: 4 / 6  Does Not Intersect
NE Querying: 3 / 6  Does Not Intersect
SW Querying: 6 / 6  Does Intersect!
Found Point  665.36365   379.79324 
Descending
NW Querying: 1 / 6  Does Not Intersect
NE Querying: 0 / 6  Does Not Intersect
SW Querying: 0 / 6  Does Intersect!
SE Querying: 0 / 6  Does Intersect!
Raising
SE Querying: 5 / 6  Does Intersect!
Found Point  772.9317    375.3352 
Raising
SW Querying: 6 / 6  Does Not Intersect
SE Querying: 6 / 6  Does Intersect!
Found Point  790.5205    386.4734 
Found Point  633.3443    390.43515 
Found Point  797.5499    397.1355 
Descending
NW Querying: 6 / 6  Does Intersect!
Found Point  723.5054    450.78967 
Found Point  741.98676   389.52292 
Found Point  683.0763    488.69083 
NE Querying: 4 / 6  Does Intersect!
Found Point  775.3038    432.92847 
SW Querying: 6 / 6  Does Not Intersect
SE Querying: 4 / 6  Does Not Intersect
Raising
Raising
Found: 9
```

The correct output image:
[image: Non bugged output, selected points are green.]

The following is an example of incorrect output in the same window that should have returned 3 points:

```
Querying: 6 / 6     Does Intersect!
Descending
NW Querying: 6 / 6  Does Not Intersect
NE Querying: 6 / 6  Does Not Intersect
SW Querying: 6 / 6  Does Intersect!
Descending
NW Querying: 3 / 6  Does Not Intersect
NE Querying: 5 / 6  Does Not Intersect
SW Querying: 6 / 6  Does Not Intersect
SE Querying: 6 / 6  Does Not Intersect
Raising
SE Querying: 6 / 6  Does Not Intersect
Raising
Found: 0
```

This is the window that accompanied the incorrect output. (Found points change to pure green.)
[image: Quadtree bug demonstration.]

I haven't been able to spot a pattern to which regions produce the correct output but my instincts say regions on the left are incorrect more often.

The full file is available [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1quhSgBVD5xorLmKuhzljP3avTOP-mW8m/view?usp=sharing) so you can run it if you need to but I'm stumped and I've come back to this a few times over the last week. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, this was a difficult problem to find (at least, I hope I solved it).

The problem is with your definition of `rW` and `rH` in `setup()`:

```
rW = constrain(randomGaussian(),-1,1)*width/6;
rH = constrain(randomGaussian(),-1,1)*height/6;
```

You can't have negative values for `rW` or `rH`. For example, suppose we test the following values (suppose the `y` values intersect as well):

```
rW = -100;
rX = 500
x = 256;
w = 256;
```

Ideally, `intersects()` would test as follows:

```
         !(400 >= 512 || 600 <= 512)
/*-->*/  !(false || false)
/*-->*/  true //(yes, they intersect)
```

but what actually happens is

```
         !(rX-rW >= x+w || rX+rW <= x-w)
/*-->*/  !(500-(-100) >= 256+256 || 500+(-100) <= 256-256)
/*-->*/  !(600 >= 512 || 400 <= 0)
/*-->*/  !(true || false)
/*-->*/  false //(no, they do not intersect)
```

It's like you're testing the wrong sides of the region.

This is a pretty easy fix, just use `abs()` when you define `rW` and `rH`:

```
rW = abs(constrain(randomGaussian(),-1,1))*width/6;
rH = abs(constrain(randomGaussian(),-1,1))*height/6;
```

Comment: I knew I would feel like a total idiot when it was solved *facepalm* thank you so much. It never occured to me I would have negative rectangles. I realise now I didn't even include the problematic code! Thank you so much. I'll include a LBYL test in the appropriate functions. I have no idea how long it would have taken me to find this and I didn't have the time because of exams. I know we aren't supposed to leave "Thank You" comments but this is a fairly inactive post so I hope its ok. You've helped me a lot during exam season when this is a project I can't be devoting this much time to.